# Set the correct fill color in translucent figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Suppose I draw two translucent rectangles:

- the red bigger one lays on the main layer
- the green smaller one lays on the back layer

where "red" is the real color, and "green" is the mixed color. In other words, "green" is **what I want to see**. If I set `green`, it will mix with "red" and present the color approximate to "yellow".

If I want to set the correct fill color, a little calculation is needed. It is so inefficient that every time I draw a translucent graph emmbeded in other one I have to calculate the real color it should be! So are there some easy ways to tackle this problem?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{back}
  \pgfsetlayers{back, main}
  \fill[red, fill opacity=0.3] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
    \fill[green, fill opacity=0.3] (1, 1) rectangle (3, 3);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
In `xcolor`, `red!30!blue` is equivalent to `0.3*red + 0.7*blue`. If we look through a red layer with opacity of 0.3 to see a blue thing, the real color we will see is `red!30!blue`. I write some code to verify them.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{red1}{RGB}{255, 178, 178}
\definecolor{mix}{RGB}{201, 178, 125}
\tikzset{
  A/.style={rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm, text opacity=1},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{back}
  \pgfsetlayers{back, main}
  \node[A, fill=red, fill opacity=.3] at (0, 0) {red};
  \node[A, fill=red!30] at (1, 0) {red};
  \node[A, fill=red1] at (2, 0) {red1};
  \node[A, fill=red, fill opacity=.3] at (0, -1) {};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
    \node[A, fill=green, fill opacity=.3] at (0, -1) {real};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \node[A, fill=mix] at (1, -1) {calc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is right. Then if I am looking through a red layer with opacity of 0.3, and I see a `green!30` color, what is the real color or which color should be mixed with `red!30` to yield `green!30`? I solve the equation `0.3*red + 0.7*unknow = 0.3*green + 0.7 * white`, but the result `(255, 255, 364)` is just out of range.

**Why I did not put the smaller rectangle on the top layer?**

Because it need. See the code below. The line of the right rectangle in the main layer is blocked.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{back}
  \pgfsetlayers{back, main}
  \fill[draw, fill=red, fill opacity=0.3] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
  \draw (0, 2) -- (4, 2);
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
    \fill[green, fill opacity=0.3] (1, 1) rectangle (3, 3);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \fill[draw, fill=red, fill opacity=0.3] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \draw (0, 2) -- (4, 2);
    \fill[green!30] (1, 1) rectangle (3, 3);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that on a rgb system, red, green and blue are basic colors, which means that they cannot be produced mixing other colors.

Comment: By the way, in [`xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor/doc) documentation you'll find the formulas used for mixing colors in several systems.

Comment: Try to append `\fill[fill=white!70!green!70!red]  (1,1) |- (3,3) -- cycle;` at the end of your `tikzpicture`...

Comment: But I'm not sure to understand your question.

Comment: If you want to see green, why do you put the green rectangle in the background layer instead of on top?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see the bottom of the edited question

Comment: Why then don't you use three layers? Or draw the line later=

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can you give me an example of three layers? The line is the part of the customized shape through `\pgfdeclareshape` that is drawn in `foregroundpath`, so it is impossible to be drawn later.

Comment: You may want to look at the `blend group` discussion on p. 352 of pgfmanual v.3.1.4. However, I am also not sure I understand your question. In the last example. you only need to assign the layers in such a way that the black line is on top, the green rectangle below and the red one lowest.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Is it possible to draw and fill the path of the shape in two different layers that are defined outside the shape?

Comment: I think so, but never tried. What these layers do is to essentially change the order of execution by putting stuff in boxes and recycling them in the appropriate order, see `pgfcorelayers.code.tex`. You are supposed to define them before the `tikzpicture` or a scope anyway.